# Extract sentence(s) from same XML element value string

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am looking to extract sentence(s) from same XML element value string, using XSL.

**Requirements:**

Each sentence(s) will end up in XHTML result file paragraph tags. The amount of sentence(s) that goes into each XHTML paragraph, might vary. It is always each dot that controls the end of a sentence. The XML data can be spread on different lines. The amount of sentence in the XML node can be larger then explained in below code so I cannot hardcode the positions of the different sentences.

**What I have tried to solve the problem:**

I managed to locate the first sentence by "substring-before" the first dot.

**Question:**

Is there a "best practice" how to subset XML text string sentences using XSL2.0 and how would that be applied in below code?

You find below code here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/asoTJE/2

---

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<library>
    <books>
        <chapters>
            <chapterOne>
                A piece of text. Another string. 
                Something, else here.
                </chapterOne>
        </chapters>
    </books>
</library>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://www.example.org/1"
    >

  <xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/library/books/chapters/chapterOne">
    
    <html>
        <head><title>MyTitle</title></head>
        <body>
            
            <!-- Works -->
            <p>
                Sentence-1. First sentence (in same chapter): 
                Cut after found first dot.
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '.')" />.
            </p>
    
            <!-- Not yet found a way to solve -->
    
            <p>
                
                Sentence-3 (in same chapter): 
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </p>
            
            <!-- Not yet found a way to solve -->
            
            <p>
                Extracted sentences, e.g. sentence-1 and sentence-2 (in same chapter): 
                Cut after second dot.
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </p>
            
            <!-- Not yet found a way to solve -->
            
            <p>
                Extracted sentences, e.g. sentence-1 and sentence-3 (in same chapter): 
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </p>
            
        </body>
    </html>
    
    
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XHTML result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html xmlns="http://www.example.org/1">
   <head>
      <title>MyTitle</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>
         Sentence-1. First sentence (in same chapter): 
         Cut after found first dot.
         
         A piece of text.
         
      </p>
      <p>
         
         Sentence-3 (in same chapter): 
         
         A piece of text. Another string. 
         Something, else here.
         
      </p>
      <p>
         Extracted sentences, e.g. sentence-1 and sentence-2 (in same chapter): 
         Cut after second dot.
         
         A piece of text. Another string. 
         Something, else here.
         
      </p>
      <p>
         Extracted sentences, e.g. sentence-1 and sentence-3 (in same chapter): 
         
         A piece of text. Another string. 
         Something, else here.
         
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply *tokenize* the text, using the period character as the separator?

Comment: Tokenize() is what you want but you better be sure your initial requirement is correct. As in ... you have no numbers like 3.25 or sentences that end with other punctuation like "?" or URLs like "stackoverflow.com"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://www.example.org/1"
    >

  <xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/library/books/chapters/chapterOne">
    
    <html>
        <head><title>MyTitle</title></head>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'[.]')">
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                  <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />.
                  </p>
                </xsl:if>
            
                
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- Works -->

        </body>
    </html>
    
    
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```